# How to output c++ type information during compilation

Tags: c++, types

everyone.
I am debugging some problem of type mismatch of a heavily templated class. I would like to know c++ type information during compilation, so I write this:

```
#pragma message typeinfo(var)
```

It just do not work.

So I am here asking for some help. I am not sure if it is possible. But I think the compiler must know the type information during compilation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The preprocessor is not going to help you much itself at compile time.  It's job is preprocessing, which happens before compile time.

If the idea is to output type information at **compile time** then try the following

```
template <typename...> struct WhichType;
class Something {};

int main() {
    WhichType<Something>{};
}
```

[Live example here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vj1nWPUU2IPEkuBg).  When you compile this you should get an error that gives you the type of whatever is inside the templates when trying to instantiate `WhichType`.  This was a neat trick I picked up from Scott Meyers' Effective Modern C++ book.  It seems to work perfectly on most mainstream compilers that I have encountered so far.

If you want to get the type information at **runtime**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    auto integer = int{};
    cout << typeid(integer).name() << endl;
}
```

---

**Note** Don't get too comfortable with RTTI (RunTime Type Information) via `typeid`, C++ also offers several compile time type introspection utilities http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits.

Comment: I would like to point that if you are using mainline compilers like gcc and clang the method is working, compiler prints the information we need. But especially in embedded world, if you are using different compiler, this method may not work! (Scott Meyes' method, I mean.)

Answer (score 1):

I use a type printer helper function, which simply bases on the gcc predefined macro `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`. Simply write a templated function which eats everthings and call it from the point where you need to know which type your template expands to. For me it was very helpful to use such a function in case of SFINAE problems and others.

```
template <typename ... T>
void TemplatePrint(T ... args )
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    auto any = std::tuple_cat( std::tuple<int, double>{}, std::tuple<std::string>{} );
    TemplatePrint( any );
}
```

You did not tag your question to a specific compiler, so you maybe need to search for equivalents on other compilers.

On C++ con some year ago a talk was about:
https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2016/02/use-templight-and-templar-to-debug-cpp-templates.html. Maybe this will help to get strange template problems solved.

Comment: Great solution. However, I am looking for a compile-time solution to print type information because compiler shows some type error before I can run the program.